# Make a file accesible by PHP but not from the outside

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, permissions, freebsd

My host gives me two folders for my use, a `/home/public/` which is where the pages go, and `/home/private/`, which is for my personal use. I would like for PHP to create a file that's readable by me from the machine but not by anyone else over the internet. Making the file in the public folder causes this problem. I thought about making the file owned by the apache group, but I'm not a member of it. It would be nice if I could put the file in my private directory, but understandably, I get access error when trying to write to a file in it. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many packages require program / script accessible subdirectories within the html or public hierarchy.

Since you are (I assume) running on a shared service using suPHP or equiv this will only run scripts in the owners UID so this isn't available.  I've a adopted a very simply convention: if any file or folder name starts with _ or . then access via a URI is forbidden.  This is by a simple rule that I place in any `.htaccess` file with

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^_|/_|^\.|/\.)" forbidden
<Files *>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Deny from env=forbidden
</Files>
```

Another way to do this is with a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule (^_|/_|^\.|/\.)            -                  [forbidden]
```

This has the advantage that you can adopt this extremely simple convention for any include or data directories that you may wish access within your scripts but do *not* want them browseable via URI.

### Footnote

I am a little confused about your statement:

> It would be nice if I could put the file in my private directory, but understandably, I get access error when trying to write to a file in it.

Is this one of these funnies where the service provider's UID owns /home/private/ and you only have read access through your GID?  My ISP does the same to dump thing like logfiles.  I can read but not write or delete.  That's why I use `/public/_private`.  Sorry for the oxymoron.

Comment: @footnote: I have